# Bootstrap grid not utilizing the full width of the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3. I need to populate a "row" with a search bar and two buttons. My problem is the row do not stretch to the entire width of the page.

[image]
Here is what it looks like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-8">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="searchbar" class="form-control" placeholder="Search XXX">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" > 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create AAA</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create BBB</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Even if I make the cols as 9 and 3, the buttons stack up in the next row. I tried btn-group, same result. I want create AAA and Create BBB buttons to float to the right. Is there any css class I could use from Bootstrap 3 or should I write customized css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's grid system uses percentages to denote the size as X/12, where X = the number provided (so if you use `col-md-4`, it will be 4/12 = 33%, or `width: 33.33333333%`). This results in the buttons/text field will not auto-expanding to fill the rest of the space, as the intended operation is to *not* stretch.

If changing the columns to 9 and 3 causes the buttons to drop to the next row, you can keep the columns as 8 and 4, and add the following style to the div containing the buttons (whether you make it an inline style [not recommended] or create your own css class is up to you):

```
text-align: right;
```

This will move the buttons to the right, as `float: right` did not work.  The search bar and buttons will move with the browser size, however the gap between the search bar and the buttons will still be around since we have moved the buttons to the right-hand side.

**Bootply:** http://www.bootply.com/YDmOVoWvN3

Comment: Thank you Mike. I will write my own CSS to customize it then. I am surprised that Bootstrap doesn't have any css class to achieve the same.

Comment: @user2452057 Glad to hear the answer worked for you.  Feel free to mark it as accepted (the green check mark) so other visitors can see which answer worked for you.